# mysql-connector.jar vs mysql-connector.tar

Tags: mysql, eclipse, connection

I also have the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" in Eclipse.

I have found many tips and discussions about jdbc in Eclipse, however none of them work so far. I keep reading about a jar file while the official website provides only a zip or tar file.

Does this have anything to do with it?

===============================

What I've tried so far:

1. sudo apt-get install libmysql-java.
2. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ 's tar file, into /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext
3. I have no idea how to use a Classpath. But I copied what I could.

Comment: And inside the zip or tar file you don't have the .jar? If not probably you are downloading the source code.

Comment: Wow... Well, I feel stupid... Many thanks, Sir Salem.

Comment: @Salem - well done - please can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @dgood1 please mark it as solved or answer your question with the steps you made and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the .jar from that compressed file and add it to Eclipse.

Inside it you will find `mysql-connector-java-<version>-bin.jar`, which is the jar you are looking for and some other files (like source code and documentation).

Note: package `libmysql-java` indeed provides the jar you need (it is placed in `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-<version>.jar`), so if Eclipse does not find it you may need to change something in "Java Build Path".